# Testing for Null Value in LessCSS

Tags: css, less

I would like to test for whether a variable is defined before writing its CSS property.  For example:

```
#someElement {
    if (@variable) {
        background-image: url(@variable);
    }
}
```

The reason for this is to prevent an empty `url()` property value when the variable is null.  I can't seem to find any way to do this from the LessCSS documentation.

Comment: Direct `isdefined` or `isundefined` kind of function is currently not available in Less. [This](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1400)  is an open feature request asking for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how such things are resolved in "Less Way" (that's why the feature is marked with "low priority" at the Less repo):

`library.less`:

```
@variable: null; // or whatever meaningful non-string value

#someElement {
    & when (isstring(@variable)) {
        background-image: url(@variable);
    }
}
```

`user.less`:

```
@import "library.less";
@variable: "foo.bar/baz.png";
```

That's it.